# Special characters in request parameter

Tags: java, spring, rest

In my REST based API(spring boot &REST) I have following parameters for my GET call

```
@RequestParam(required = false ) String name, @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "1") Long page,
            @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "20") Long pageSize.
```

When the user calls my GET method with some special characters an error occurred.

Request format is given below:

```
http://localhost:8015/accounts/1/things/?name=%23%$25%2$3%5e
```

In my controller sometimes name is null and sometimes I get the following error

```
2017-02-24 14:31:29.396 -DEBUG [nucleus-thing-service,6cae9c64f94df6a6,6cae9c64f94df6a6,true] 4288 --- [nio-8015-exec-4] c.c.n.thing.controller.ThingsController  : Log after calling - com.cantiz.nucleus.thing.controller.ThingsController.getAll
2017-02-24 14:31:29.398 -ERROR [nucleus-thing-service,6cae9c64f94df6a6,6cae9c64f94df6a6,true] 4288 --- [nio-8015-exec-4] c.c.n.thing.controller.ThingsController  : Log after throwingcom.cantiz.nucleus.thing.controller.ThingsController.getAllException : java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '#'
    at java.util.Formatter.checkText(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Well, `%23%$25%2$3%5e` is not a valid parameter value. You need to properly encode your parameters before sending them. Also, when asking about an exception, post the code (and inputs) causing it, and the exact and complete exception stack trace.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is a QA scenario.They raised an issue based on this.

Comment: Well, then tell QA that they can't expect invalid HTTP parameters to be parsed as they would like.

Comment: Use `@controlleradvice` in this way you can handle those error and send human readable response to the end user. You can check this [Link](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-exception-handling-controlleradvice-annotation/)

Comment: Sometimes you don't want to send a nice error.

Comment: As @JB Nizet mentions, you need to encode your data correctly. The $ characters in the encoded name parameter are part of the problem.  If those are removed, the encoded name=%23%25%23%5e - and decoded, it becomes: name=#%#^ - which absolutely looks like something a QA engineer would request.